# CSV Reader losing escape characters

Tags: java

I am attempting to read a file with the following info:

```
"message":"{\"n_number\":\"000116314\"}
```

When I try to use a CSVReader I lose the escape characters(). When I use the BufferedReader directly, I can keep the escape characters. How do I modify my code that uses the CSVReader so it keeps the escape characters?

Failing code

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    Character delimiter = '\u0001';

    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader)
            .withCSVParser(new CSVParserBuilder()
                    .withSeparator(delimiter).build()).build();

    List<Map<String, Object>> output = new ArrayList<>();

    mappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(columns);
    mappingStrategy.setType(MyData.class);
    CsvToBean<MyData> csvbean = new CsvToBean<MyData>();
    csvbean.setCsvReader(csvReader);
    csvbean.setMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy);
    List<MyData> myData = csvbean.parse();
```

This produces:

```
"message":"{"n_number":"000116314"}
```

Working code

```
        StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            resultStringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
```

Comment: Is the CSV data not supposed to be quoted and escaped? E.g. if the info is `"foo":"a , b \" c ' d \\ e"` in column 2 of the CSV with a number in column 1, wouldn't the CSV line need to be `42,"\"foo\":\"a , b \\\" c ' d \\\\ e\""`? The info shown in the question is not CSV-escaped, so it's a bad CSV file. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Are you sure this is a CSV file? It looks more like a JSON file.